# How do I install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on a MacBook 2,1 with 32 bit EFI?

Tags: uefi, bootloader, macbook

I have a MacBook 2,1 (2007) and it has a 64 bit CPU, but 32 bit EFI. I have seen all sorts of things on the internet, but my DVD drive is broken and I can't seem to find anything that allows me to install Ubuntu on my computer. I have used this guide here, https://mattgadient.com/linux-dvd-images-and-how-to-for-32-bit-efi-macs-late-2006-models/ but it only works on a DVD or CD. I only have access to a 32 bit Debian system, and MacOS.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the Mac currently boot to MacOS? Can you make it boot to the USB (hold option key or whatever)?

Comment: It boots to snow leopard. I found this guide. https://medium.com/@realzedgoat/a-sorta-beginners-guide-to-installing-ubuntu-linux-on-32-bit-uefi-machines-d39b1d1961ec I used the unetbootin method from a mac and then I put in the 32 bit efi file that was linked in the post and I used refind https://sourceforge.net/projects/refind/ It won't work using the option key. You need refind. (For anyone that wants to install on their own machine.)

Answer (score 2):

My answer is maybe a bit late but the're is on this site a method (option 4) to install the distro on a usb stick : https://mesom.de/efi32boot/index.html
I've tried it and it works (I can boot from usb drive) but for the moment, I'm unable to boot from Ubuntu once installed on the hard drive.
Regards,
Speedy67